# Django 2.0, URL Routes Causing Max Recursion with check_method

Tags: django, django-views, docker-compose, django-urls, django-class-based-views

I'm totally new to Django, and I'm having a problem adding a Django "app" to a created Django "project". I'm using Docker and Docker-Compose and when I try to build and spin up my instance with the "documents" app added it throws maximum recursion errors.

This problem is NOT present if I remove the documents app from the project, so there's obviously something misconfigured with my app.

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong to set my default URL ('') to the Index view in documents?

**Directory Structure**

```
app/
  |-django_nlp/
    |-settings.py
    |-urls.py
    |-wsgi.py
  |-documents/
    |-templates/
      |-index.html
    |-apps.py
    |-views.py
  |-Dockerfile
  |-docker-compose.yml
  |-manage.py
```

**django_nlp/settings.py**

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# /usr/src/app

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'ixoz#2d4=m#k#%1#!hhr2ei82t4x$$e)n9oxrq66mzq556k59@'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'documents'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_nlp.urls'

#Get the absolute path of the settings.py file's directory
BASE_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__ ))
# /usr/src/app/django_nlp


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/django_templates" or
    # "C:/www/django/templates".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.

    #Add Templates to the absolute directory
    # os.path.join(BASE_PATH, "templates")
)

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR,
            BASE_PATH
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_nlp.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

**django_nlp/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

# from documents import views
# import documents
from documents.views import Index


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', Index.as_view())
    # url(r'$^', documents.views.index, name='index')
]
```

**documents/views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import TemplateView


# def index(request):
    # return HttpResponse('Hello, welcome to the index page.')

class Index(TemplateView):
    template_name = "text-form.html"
    data = {'text': ''}

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(data=self.data)
        return render(request, self.template_name, data)
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: you should paste the error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you working on Django 2.0, you should read this docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/, the url configuration in this version has changes. But, if you realy want to use regex in Django 2.0, you can change:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
```

to;

```
from django.urls import re_path
```

---

example in your case;

```
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', Index.as_view())
    # url(r'$^', documents.views.index, name='index')
]
```

to;

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^$', Index.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed that change moving to 2.0.

Comment: This fixed part of my issue, and the other issue I had was an incorrect implementation of a Class-Based View with form data. I also needed to add from django import forms  and to pass my variables to my template via "self.variableName". Now it works! Thanks a lot!